# what's a 403 570 error in Nginx?

Tags: http, nginx

Nginx server running, docroot pointed to

```
/srv/www/html
```

When I try to access an index.php in the docroot I get

> [22/Aug/2016:13:40:31 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 570 "-" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36" "-"

I have created an entire directory tree in `srv` chmodded to nginx.  I have grepped ps aux to make sure nginx is running as nginx and it is.  There's nothing I can find of any use on the Internet.  Default server block says:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /srv/www/html/;
```

no app blocks running yet.  Any idea why this is throwing that error?  What's a 570 status? Never seen that before.

Comment: Can you paste all your vhost configuration? What happen when you go to `http://localhost/index.php`

Answer (score 2):

so `403` is a HTTP status code (Forbidden), and `570` is how many bytes was sent in request. You can read more about logs format here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html